# Output product custom field values in order email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I have a custom field for a Woocommerce's product, and I want to display it's value in order emails.

As I'm using custom product submission form, I added this code for custom field below to create a custom field:

```
<?php 
    WCVendors_Pro_Form_Helper::select( array(  
        'post_id'       => $object_id,
        'class'         => 'select2',
        'id'            => 'wcv_custom_product_ingredients', 
        'label'         => __( 'What time?', 'wcvendors-pro' ), 
        'placeholder'   => __( 'Pick a time', 'wcvendors-pro' ),
        'wrapper_start' => '<div class="all-100">',
        'wrapper_end'   => '</div>',
        'desc_tip'      => 'true', 
        'description'   => __( 'Pick a time', 'wcvendors-pro' ),
        'options'       => array( '12:00 midnight' => __('12:00 midnight', 'wcv_custom_product_ingredients'), '12:15 midnight'=> __('12:15 midnight', 'wcv_custom_product_ingredients') )
) );
?>
```

I also tried adding code below to functions.php, but this only displays "What time?" without value in order emails...

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'wcv_ingredients_email');
function wcv_ingredients_email() {
    $output = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wcv_custom_product_ingredients', true );
    echo 'What time? ' . $output . '<br>';
}
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the correct hook, but you just forgot the hook arguments in the hooked function.

> Also as you are targeting a product custom field value, and as in an order you can have many items (products), **the code below will display this value for each order item.**

Try the code below, it works now:

```
// Tested on WooCommerce version 2.6.x and 3+ — For simple products only.
add_action('woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'wcv_ingredients_email', 10, 4);
function wcv_ingredients_email( $order,  $sent_to_admin,  $plain_text,  $email ){
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item_values){
        // Get the product ID for simple products (not variable ones)
        $product_id = $item_values['product_id'];
        $output = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'wcv_custom_product_ingredients', true );
        echo 'What time? ' . $output . '<br>';
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for this! Would you be kind to tell me how to include values from this custom field on woocommerce's order pages?

Comment: @MarkoI. Do you mean in order receive page and my account order view page (customer order pages)?

Comment: @MarkoI. I have certainly answer this already more than once. I need to retrieve my answers. Where do you want to output that exactly?

Comment: I want to output it in order details table at https://example.com/my-account/view-order/00000/ , that is, on single view order page. (Under the product name would be great.). And also in the order details table when order is received, on this page: https://example.com/checkout/order-received/00000/?key=wc_order_58ef9bf590bcf